# Inventory not decrementing after the order is placed - Magento 2.1 upgraded from Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory, manage-stock

We have recently upgraded our website from Magento 2.0.2 to Magento 2.1. We are having strange issue with stock management.

When an order is placed, product quantity is not auto decremented. I tried changing website id from `cataloginventory_stock_item` and `cataloginventory_stock_status` as I thought it might be a problem with website association.

This had no effect though. I checked for the bug and found an reported issue on git https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5945

Does anyone else face the same issue? It would be helpful if someone can provide an insight on this.

Comment: Yes facing the same issue...uploading the product and other changes affects..but after payment completes, qty is not getting reduced!

Comment: If yu have found any solution, please update on the same!

Comment: I didn't found the exact solution however this problem seems to be of website id. In Magento2.0 default website ID is 1 whereas in 2.1 its 0. To avoid any future bugs, we deleted all old entries and reimported all products. It works fine now

Comment: Im using Magento 2.2.0...Do i have to change the value to anythng?

Comment: And is ur "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" in admin Yes?

Comment: Yes, after reimporting all products the stock is working fine. For you to correct the entry you might have to change the website id. I haven't explored it much due to time constraint but you can post the solution if you do.